# Gridview Selectedrow color All Pages in one move

Tags: gridview

I have a project and I have about 50 grid and is not sensible to make one by one have you any idea ?

asp:Gridview

Asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Use a Repeater element to create each one, if they are similar/identical.